# Issues logging in ldap root DN

Tags: openldap

I almost been stuck a day on the following issue,

I installed LDAP using: apt-get install slapd

and use the following configuration:

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema


allow bind_v2
loglevel    0
moduleload  back_sbdb.la

database    bdb
suffix      "dc=test,dc=nl"
rootdn      "cn=Directory Manager,dc=test,dc=nl"
rootpw      test

directory   /var/lib/ldap

index   objectClass                     eq
index   userPassword                        eq,pres
index   givenName,mail,mobile,sn,title,cn,description       eq,sub,pres
index   displayName                     eq,sub,pres
index   postalAddress,facsimileTelephoneNumber          pres

access to *
  by self write
  by * read
```

and I then try to bind using

```
ldapsearch -D cn=Directory Manager,dc=test,dc=nl -w test
```

but I still recieve the error ldap_bind: Invalid Credentials (49)

Anyone has any idea or clues what this could be?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using quotes like;

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=Directory Manager,dc=test,dc=nl" -w test
```

Space character in Directory Manager may cause the problem.

Edit: Also, are you sure you don't need -h -p parameters?

```
-h     The host name of the directory server
-p     The port number of the directory server
```

Edit2: Just figured out what is wrong. You are using rootpw unencrypted in your slapd config file. You should use an encrypted password created by `slappasswd` tools output. This may cause problems under special circumstances.

Check this link for details: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ldap-quickstart.html

Comment: Still doesn't work. if I try just searching for the entry without actual binding I can find it just fine (ldapsearch -b dc=test,dc=nl -x 'cn=Directory Manager'

Comment: I did some testing into the -h and -p port. but if I enter bogus information it tells me it cannot connect. if I use -h localhost and -p 389 it gives me the ldap_bind error again. so connection is fine.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you could try:

- Turn on more verbose logging (`loglevel 255`), and see if anything shows up in the log file.
- Verify that the server really is reading the configuration file you think by checking the access time on the slapd.conf file (`ls -lu slapd.conf`)
- Try binding using an invalid dn (`ldapsearch -D cn=no-such-user -w test`) and see if the error message changes (if so, that confirms that the problem is with the password, not the dn).

Answer (score 0):

Try `man ldapsearch`.

I'm not really sure on debian/ubuntu, but in FreeBSD you need to add a `-x` to use simple authentication instead of SASL. I think this might be your issue?

Also, you could use `-W` instead of passing the password plain text on the commmand line.